# Using FBEvents activateApp on IOS and phonegap doesn't post to Facebook Insights

Tags: ios, facebook, api, sdk, cordova

I'm looking to integrate the FaceBook SDK into my application to track mobile app installs using the "activateApp" method.  ([integration referencePage](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/))  I was able to get this working on Android, but only after discovering that you must have the Facebook Native application installed and logged-in in order to use it.  Try as I might I am unable to get the IOS to make the same call and for it to be registered on my Facebook Developer App page as a "Last Mobile Install".  Here is the code I'm using:  (The App ID listed in the example code is intentionally wrong, the one I have in my running application is a copy/paste of the App ID on the facebook app page)

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{   
     [FBSettings setDefaultAppID:@"123456789123456"];
     [FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorAppEvents, nil]];
     [FBAppEvents activateApp];}
```

After the activeApp call is made I see this log statement in the console

```
2013-08-19 08:50:45.776 MyApp[258:907] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents: Recording event @ 1376920246: {
"_eventName" = "fb_mobile_activate_app";
"_logTime" = 1376920246;}
```

Upon either backgrounding the application and opening it up again I see this in the console.  Which I believe is the SDK pushing the requests out to the FB Developer App page.

```
2013-08-19 11:16:57.667 MyApp[286:907] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents Persist: Writing 1 events

2013-08-19 11:16:59.453 MyApp[286:907] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents: Recording event @ 1376929019: {
    "_eventName" = "fb_mobile_activate_app";
    "_logTime" = 1376929019; 
}

2013-08-19 11:16:59.455 MyApp[286:907] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents Persist: Read 1 events

2013-08-19 11:16:59.457 MyApp[286:907] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents Persist: Clearing

2013-08-19 11:16:59.651 MyApp[286:907] FBSDKLog: FBAppEvents: Flushed @ 1376929019, 2 events due to 'PersistedEvents' - 
{
    "advertiser_id" = "9534FA44-DDE9-40E6-B10F-DDBD174860B4";
    "advertiser_tracking_enabled" = 1;
    "application_tracking_enabled" = 1;
    attribution = "2770A653-BE20-4679-B955-CDBF621D5B5C";
    event = "CUSTOM_APP_EVENTS";
}

Events: [
  {
    "_eventName" : "fb_mobile_activate_app",
    "_logTime" : 1376929009
  },
  {
    "_eventName" : "fb_mobile_activate_app",
    "_logTime" : 1376929019
  }
]
Flush Result : Success
```

I pretty sure the SDK is imported correctly and I've also tried this scenario is the most barebones stand-alone IOS app and I still don't see any reaction on our Facebook App page.

Let me know if any additional information would be useful and I can add it here.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Any news. I have the same pb...

Comment: FYI, I'm not seeing them in the new insights UI but if I use the old one I can see all of them. Maybe the new UI needs more data. I don't know.

Comment: this answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305956/how-do-i-implement-facebook-mobile-install-ad-tracking-in-phonegap-cordova-proje?rq=1

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this, I am having the same issue