# How do I implement Facebook Mobile Install Ad tracking in Phonegap/Cordova project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cordova

Ok, so I've got a "completed" iOS phonegap/cordova project, using version 3.4 in xcode 5. I know I need to integrate the facebook sdk in order to track the installs for mobile ads.

Will simply integrating the sdk as per Facebook's instructions here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/ do the job, or do I need to use the entire facebook connect plugin as outlined here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin being that I only need to track installs?

Also, when this is taken care of I need to add the following to the UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive selector

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:YOUR_APP_ID];
[FBAppEvents activateApp];
```

Yet I can find no clear answer on exactly where I need to place this, (I have little to no knowledge of obj-c), where and in which file in my xcode project do I need to place this? I did find this out from a transcript of an open session on phonegap, it didn't help me much but may mean something to you:

*Sometimes, some SDK or others ask us to add some lines in the objective-C, like Facebook for "Mobile App Install Ads" they ask to add "[FBSettings publishInstall:YOUR_APP_ID]" in UIApplicationDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive selector - but with phonegap project, we have not this method, so is there a equivalent in the code generated by phonegap?
A: If you are developing locally using Xcode, you can access this method in the application delegate class. This is not available inside of the PhoneGap Build service.*

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oliver, did you ever solve this problem?  I'd like to know as I'm currently dealing with the same issue.  Thanks.

Comment: I think so having just looked at it. Let me test it and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @cranberry see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the detailed answer, Oliver.  Ya saved me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having looked at this issue again, the answer is pretty simple.

Follow the instructions for creating an app and installing the SDK:

It tells you exactly how to do this for iOS here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

Make sure to follow the instructions to the letter and that you add the relevant rows/values to your project's .plist file.

The final piece of information you'll need is understanding the import of the Facebook SDK header file into the AppDelegate.m file in your Xcode project and the applicationDidBecomeActive selector.

In your project's ApplicationDelegate.m file copy `#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>` directly below your other import statements. Hint: they look similar and are near the top.

Now copy the following into your AppDelegate.m replacing the dummy app id @"123456789" with your facebook app id. Place this code directly above `@end` in your AppDelegate.m file.

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [FBSettings setDefaultAppID: @"123456789"];
    [FBAppEvents activateApp];

}
```

That's it. Now you can try an install of your app onto your development device and check it's reporting correctly by visiting your app dashboard on Facebook, scrolling down to the bottom, or finding the section about latest installs.

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work using the cordova facebook connect plugin?? https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: Depends what you mean by this? If all you are looking to do is ad tracking you do not need the facebook connect plugin at all. But even if you need the facebook connect plugin for other FB integration this ad tracking setup is effectively separate and should work with or without the facebook connect plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It's done automatically by the javascript sdk:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent#examples

[image]

Comment: Hey, would you please elaborate more and give some step by step instruction

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer, but I'm in a similar position. My understanding is yes you need to install the Facebook SDK, and yes you'll need to add the ObjectiveC config stuff to UIApplicationDelegate. However I believe you do not need the phonegap-facebook-plugin and I would suggest you stay clear of it, at least while it has 216 open issues and lags the iOS Facebook SDK by several versions. Of course, your mileage may vary, but I'm fairly certain it is not required for Mobile Ads tracking.