# What is Cordova's Equivelant of UIApplicationDelegate

Tags: ios, facebook, cordova, sdk

I am trying to set up [Facebook's Ad Tracking SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads) on my iOS app.  It requires that I place a line of code into `UIApplicationDelegate`.  As I am developing on Cordova, `UIApplicationDelegate` seems to be missing.  Can anyone enlighten me as to where `UIApplicationDelegate` is hiding, or an alternative place to put the line of code?  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

For anyone having a similar problem, I was able to find more information from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305956/how-do-i-implement-facebook-mobile-install-ad-tracking-in-phonegap-cordova-proje?noredirect=1#comment37482679_20305956).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put those lines of code in AppDelegate (`AppDelegate.m`).