# Cordova / phonegap tracking APPs install with Facebook SDK

Tags: facebook, cordova

Related question: [How do I implement Facebook Mobile Install Ad tracking in Phonegap/Cordova project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305956)

I have a working cordova/phonegap application. I would like to track the APP install using the plugin facebook. I installed the cordova facebook connect plugin with:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="myappid" --variable APP_NAME="myappname"
```

The plugin is installed and usable as this report 'true':

```
alert('fb plugin usable: ' + typeof facebookConnectPlugin != 'undefined')
```

However I am no seeing anything in the "Most recently logged events" in the facebook developer section for this app. I added the correct Package Name and Class Name in the settings but the events are not just showing up.

Is there anything that I am missing or more info that I can provide ? I cannot find a good tutorial on this that explains the full process.

Should the APP install event just be logged by adding the plugin without any JS call in the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dug a bit in the plugin implementation and noted the **activateApp** was not implement at all. I cloned the repo and add the functionality for Android [following the [FB guide for android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-apps/mobile-app-ads#add-sdk) ]:

The modifications required on the code are: [code changes in plugin](https://github.com/dawez/phonegap-facebook-plugin/commit/d25de61b5b43311cf68e14148a8d48b4f61b47fc) and : [how to use in the JS code](https://github.com/dawez/phonegap-facebook-plugin/commit/004cd9e2c566a005ec5abbd5ca5dc6163b3fe6b8). In this way I can just call

```
facebookConnectPlugin.activateApp(fb_success, fb_fail);
```

where the callbacks are just dummy empty function.

and the FB is SDK tracks when there is an installation. I noticed however that the events are generated only when there is a FB app installed on the device [do not know if this is supposed to be like that].

**UPDATE**
Probably my solution is old, I guess that now the official plugin for Facebook has already the feature implemented directly without the need of any additional customization in the JS files or touching the Java files.

Comment: Regarding "events are generated only when there is a FB app installed on the device"  This is by design it seems. FB first detects relationship of real FB user to mobile device ID when user actually logs into the official FB app / product. Then when your app uses the FB SDK, it only reports the device ID back to FB. There is no need for user to do the FB login in the 3rd-party app. FB infers the user through combination of pairs of data: your_App-to-device_id + device_id-to-FB_user_login_somewhere_else.

Comment: This trick is not working with ionic1 cordova app, can you have any good reference about it