# Phonegap Build using Phonegap Facebook Plugin

Tags: facebook, cordova, facebook-javascript-sdk, phonegap-build, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I'm using PhoneGap Build. I'm using this plugin here: https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin only to add install tracking for a Facebook ad I have setup for mobile ads when people install the app after clicking the mobile Facebook ad.

In the Facebook SDK here under "4. Enable Install Tracking": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk

it says: "To enable install tracking call the App Events logger once your application becomes active."

In this plugin's README under Events, it says:

"Activation events are automatically tracked for you in the plugin."

Does this mean that there is no code to write, that once I only have to add the plugin to the config xml and it will automatically call FB.AppEvents.activateApp() ?

I have attempted to call FB.AppEvents.activateApp() manually using the Facebook SDK for Javascript but get an error AppEvents undefined.

Comment: Ask the author of the plugin. How do we know what the author meant?

Comment: I have posted an issue in Github, however due to the urgency of this, I posted on SO to see if any experts on here have a solution.

Comment: everyone has urgency. work around your urgency.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868984/cordova-phonegap-tracking-apps-install-with-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Facebook JS SDK documentation you'll find that it says...

> Note: App Launches and App Installs are now logged automatically. It's no longer necessary to call activateApp to log those events.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.AppEvents.LogEvent

So the readme for that plugin is correct to say it is automatic.